# Incorrect MySql result row count

Tags: mysql, sql, .net, ado.net

I'm doing some testing with the [Chinook database](https://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/) on a few different database platforms.

Here's one query I'm testing with:

```
SELECT t.`TrackId`
FROM `InvoiceLine` AS l
RIGHT OUTER JOIN `Track` AS t
     ON l.`TrackId` = t.`TrackId`
WHERE l.`TrackId` IS NOT NULL
```

Here's the behavior I'm seeing:

- MySql ([MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/)): 1984 Rows
- MySql (phpMyAdmin): 2240 Rows
- MySql ([DevArt Provider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotConnect.Express.for.MySQL/)): 2240 Rows
- Sql Server: 2240 Rows
- PostgreSQL: 2240 Rows
- Sqlite (LEFT OUTER JOIN; sqlite has no support for RIGHT): 2240 Rows

Adding `DISTINCT` to the query always results in 1984 rows across all tests, leading me to suspect that the MySql.Data ADO.NET provider is not being honest about the data that retrieves.

Any hunches as to what's going on here?

### Update

Changing the select list to a simple COUNT(*) results in 2240. I suspect a bug in the MySql.Data ADO.net provider. The database engine itself *seems* to behave correctly.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what rows it is missing and see if there is a pattern.  And that WHERE l.`TrackId` IS NOT NULL negates that right outer - you can just use a join and drop the where.

Comment: The rows that are missing are the duplicates. It's as if I asked for distinct, though I didn't. Never mind improving the SQL, that's not the purpose of the question.

Comment: OK, but if you improve the SQL does it give you the right answer?

Comment: No, the answer is still wrong.

Comment: Does count(*) give the correct answer?